# Is it ok to render string and react element inside one array from reacts perspective?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Let's imagine situation in which it's required to render `string[][]` data.

I got the following code:

```
export interface IProps {
    correctAnswers: string[][];
}

public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.props.correctAnswers.map(this.renderPlaceholderAnswers)}
        </div>
    );
}

private renderPlaceholderAnswers(answers: string[], index: number): JSX.Element {
    const last = this.props.correctAnswers.length - 1;
    const content: Array<JSX.Element | string> = [];

    if (answers.length === 0)
        content.push('JUST A SIMPLE STRING'); //there is no key, as it's a string
    else
        content.push(<SimpleAnswerList key="answers" answers={answers} />); //key to indicate inner array items

    index !== last && content.push(<hr key="divider" />); //key to indicate inner array items

    return (
        <div key={index}>  //key to indicate outer array items
            {content}
        </div>
    );
}
```

In this situation react is not complaining about missing `key` prop, so is this code valid?

I know that this code smells, but it's only for research purposes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work, and while there's not much official information out there on how React treats strings in the DOM, [React's Documentation on Reconciliation and Recursion](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children) can be pretty insightful. The docs mention that the `key` prop is necessary on all **React Elements** within a list in order to efficiently diff the virtual DOM.

React most likely treats pure strings in the DOM as their own self-sufficient keys. It's easy to tell if a string has changed in the DOM, because the very presence, position, and/or value of the string will have changed.

As for my personal preferences, I would generally stray away from this approach, as I like to enclose everything in at least a `<span>` for consistency.

Comment: Yes, I think the same. It easily could be amended via span or Fragments from react v16.2. I guess there is nothing to add, I'll accept your answer. Thanks!